# How can I use special characters with json encode?

Tags: json, special-characters

I am encoding some text with json:

```
  $json = array('result' => '',);
  $json['result'].='My name is Roger';
  echo json_encode($json);
```

My output is `My name is Roger`.

But when I write

```
  $json = array('result' => '',);
  $json['result'].='test {#[^[*]+|€~!,<€¥<=?"{*\>Ö.ßäülenwj test ';
  echo json_encode($json);
```

Then I do not get any output.

I also tested to work with `htmlspecialchars` but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe your file is ISO-8859-1/15 encoded. json_encode only works with utf8 charset.

In your test scenario you can convert the whole file to utf8 and I think you will get the right response.

Otherwise you need to convert your string to utf8 using utf8_encode("iso_string");

Hope this helps.

Grtngs
Dustin

Comment: I also checked the file encoding in textwrangler and it is set to `unicode (UTF-8)`

Comment: I tested `utf8_encode("iso_string");` but unfortunately still no result

Comment: Maybe you can try this before you encode your string to json:
`$s = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $s);`

After this you can check the differences between the old and new string so you can see, which char is responsible for this behaviour.